# Objective C blocks in an UML class diagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uml, class-diagram

I am designing an iOS library using an UML class diagram. How can I represent Objective-C blocks in UML?

Comment: I think this question is a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer: 
[UML representation for C/C++ function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663462/uml-representation-for-c-c-function-pointers)

Although it talks about function pointers, I guess it can be applied to blocks also.