# UML Class Diagram: What goes in the return type for the function if the function returns a function call?

Tags: python, uml, class-diagram

So I have a function lets say:

```
def func(self):
    ls = []
    #do something to ls 
    return self.ListParser(ls)

def ListParser(self, ls):
    files = []
    # do some stuff with ls and files
    return files
```

So in the uml class diagram what do I put for return type if it looks like this:

`+` func(self): return type

do I put:

`+` func(self): ListParser(ls)

or

`+` func(self): files[]

Do I put what it will eventually return or the function call.

Thank you.

Comment: You put what it will return, because **that's what it returns**. The call is resolved *before* it returns. It doesn't *"[return] a function call"*, it returns the result of it.

Comment: So in this case I would put + func(self): files[], because it will eventually return a list.

Comment: Put whatever you put for `ListParser`.

Comment: The signature should be `+func(self):[]` since Python is not typed and `files` is not the type but the name of a variable.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thank you, also for the argument self, I was debating whether to put self or what self is refering to like the class name.

Comment: `self` is a argument like any other. It's just mandatory for class operations and helps to distinguish from static functions which do not have a `self` parameter.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with Python enough but I recall similar construct from C++. I believe what you actually return in such case is a functionReference and I would say that's what you should show in your class. At least I would model it in such way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your question is not correct. Your function `func` does not return a function, but the result of a function. To my knowledge there is no common type representing a function. The return of an operation is a `Type`

> **9.6.4 Notation**
> If shown in a diagram, an Operation is shown as a text string of the form:
>
> ```
> [<visibility>] <name> ‘(‘ [<parameter-list>] ‘)’ [‘:’ [<return-type>] [‘[‘ <multiplicity-range> ‘]’] [‘{‘ <oper-property> [‘,’ <oper-property>]* ‘}’]]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> • `<return-type>` is the type of the return result Parameter if the Operation has one defined.

So you are more or less free in inventing you own notation if you want to return a function. That would in most case be language specific (e.g. in Swift you would show that as `() -> ()` for a void function without parameters; for Python you could 'invent' the notation `<func>` to return a function).

Now, as already said, you do not return a function, but the result of a function. And that seems to be an array. I would assume an array of strings. So I would show that as

[image]

assuming the above is part of the class `ClassWhatEver`. Note that the signature does not list the names, but the types, so for the `self` you would show the class name. It would also be possible to leave that away if you are modeling towards Python and have some modeling guidelines that say so. In that case you would need to distinguish static functions by stereotyping them like so:

[image]

N.B. You named `ListParser` with a capital `L`. Though you should stick to common naming rules and only use capital first char for classes, types, etc and not for operations. So you should name it `listParser` instead.

Comment: There's further discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663462/uml-representation-for-c-c-function-pointers

Comment: @PeteKirkham Thanks. However Uffe's solution is quite EA-centric.

Comment: @ThomasKilian thank you for this answer, I like it an believe it is explained well.